# Python cosine_similarity doesn't work for matrix with NaNs

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, similarity, cosine-similarity

Need to find **python** function that works like this **R** func:

```
proxy::simil(method = "cosine", by_rows = FALSE)
```

i.e. finds similarity matrix by pair-wise calculating cosine distance between dataframe rows. 
If NaNs are present, it should drop exact columns with NaNs in these 2 rows

[Simil function description (R)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOoha.png)

[Python error because of NaNs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ6Ed.png)

**upd**. I have also tried to delete **NaNs** in every pair of rows in loop using **cosine** func from scipy.spatial.distance. It gives the same result as in R, but works ages :(

Comment: How are you deleting the `Nans` in every pair of rows?

Comment: I drop i'th element of each vector if at least one of them is NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:  https://github.com/Midnighter/nadist, 
alternatively you can use `_chk_weights` with `nan_screen=True` as described here by metaperture here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3870, hope that helps.

I have found that Midnighter had posted the same problem previously on stackoverflow: [Compute the pairwise distance in scipy with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781461/compute-the-pairwise-distance-in-scipy-with-missing-values). There are some other solutions there but, as he moved on to cytonize it I bet they were not the best.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a mask (boolean array indicating which values are missing) and calculating pairwise cosine distances between row-vectors of matrix. As a result I received a long vector of similarities, which I then pivoted to get the similarity matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can swap `NaN` with `0` and try calculating cosine similarity then.

Comment: hi. I tried to do that. but it gives wrong result (different from the one which R simil function gives)